# Navigating in the filtered Chat room result ends in Workin on Ur problemz

Tags: bug, chat

I was looking for a transcript in some older frozen/delete chatrooms I participated in.

Therefore I visited

> [`/rooms?tab=all&sort=created&filter=rene&page=2&nohide=true`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms?tab=all&sort=created&filter=rene&page=2&nohide=true)

As that page didn't contain what I was looking for I clicked to page 3 and then to page 4. It takes a while but I assume that query times out after some time, leading to a *Oops! Something Bad Happened!* and a cat workin on ur problemz.

I don't recall it did this before so I expect there to be a regression or an index that needs tuning.

Can this be looked at when a dev is going to touch Chat?

Comment: I love that you're modestly indicating you're willing to wait half a decade :)

Comment: Apparently the opposite... devs will rush out to fix the problematic code segment or else... they gonna get _rene'd_

Comment: @kayess Wouldn't be to sure about that, considering the SO mobile app, which is discontinued somehow (the mobile devs are now working on the website, I think)

Comment: The cat is working on it. It will be fixed in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: I kinda misread "..when a dev is going to touch Chat" as "...when a dev is going to touch Cat" ...But maybe thats also contributing to a solution in this case :)

Comment: [cat = chat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appeler_un_chat_un_chat)